# Call to variadic template is ambigous

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous

I have a variadic template function that works except if I call it with an argument of the same type as `T`.

```
template <typename T, typename... Arg>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Arg&&... arg)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...));
}
```

Working call:

```
auto sahredStr = make_shared<std::string>("fubar");
```

Ambigous call:

```
std::string str = "fubar";
auto sharedStr = make_shared<std::string>(str);
```

I would like to understand what is wrong with the second call.

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/468ac0b2ab89f83a)

Comment: The latter finds `std::make_shared` via ADL

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thank you for that :)

Comment: Either change the name, or call it with `(make_shared<std::string>)(str)` syntax

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You can answer the question and I will accept it. After all, you probably saved me quite some time before I would figure it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a call to a function using an unqualified name, the name lookup procedure also considers namespaces that the types of arguments (and type template arguments thereof) are declared in - also known as *Argument Dependent Lookup*. For a `std::string`-typed argument, this means that the `make_shared` function is also searched for in the `std` namespace. As such, the set of viable overloads includes also the [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function, hence ambiguity.

A solution is to either change the name of your function to avoid conflicts with the `std`'s overload, or wrap the function name with parenthesis:

```
auto sharedStr = (make_shared<std::string>)(str);
//              ~^~                      ~^~
```

Comment: Why are the parenthesis working here? I would have used `::make_shared<std::string>(str)` to explicit select the right namespace.

Comment: @CK1 parenthesis disable ADL